# Show message "Email sending failed/successful" asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have feedback form on my mvc site and I send this form to email.
In my controller I created ErrorMessage in case email sending is failed and SuccessMessage in case email sending is successful

```
/*Feedback*/
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Feedback(string ErrorMessage)
{
    if (ErrorMessage != null)
    {
    }

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Feedback(FeedbackForm Model)
{
    string ErrorMessage, SuccessMessage;

    //email
    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    msg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    msg.Priority = MailPriority.High;

    msg.From = new MailAddress(Model.Email, Model.Name);
    msg.To.Add("tayna-anita@mail.ru");

    msg.Subject = @Resources.Global.Feedback_Email_Title + " " + Model.Company;
    string message = @Resources.Global.Feedback_Email_From + " " + Model.Name + "\n"
                    + @Resources.Global.Feedback_Email + " " + Model.Email + "\n"
                    + @Resources.Global.Feedback_Phone + " " + Model.Phone + "\n"
                    + @Resources.Global.Feedback_Company + " " +  Model.Company + "\n\n"
                    + Model.AdditionalInformation;
    msg.Body = message;
    msg.IsBodyHtml = false;

    //Attachment
    if (Model.ProjectInformation != null && !(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ProjectInformation.FileName)))
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase attFile = Model.ProjectInformation;
        if (attFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var attach = new Attachment(attFile.InputStream, attFile.FileName);
            msg.Attachments.Add(attach);
        }
    }

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("denver.corepartners.local", 55);
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.EnableSsl = false;

    try
    {
        client.Send(msg);
        SuccessMessage = "Email sending was successful"
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Feedback", "Home", ErrorMessage = "Email sending failed");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Feedback", "Home");
}
```

How can I add showing this messages in my view?

Comment: you may also setup a  viewdata("Error") = "Message Failure" within your Model's Exception  & then simply output the value of viewdata to VIEW....<%=viewData("Error")%>

Comment: Can you show me example how to add this exception to my model?

Answer (score 0):

As you are redirecting to new page use the TempData , which will be available in next request after redirect. Put the message in TempData["Message"] and output in the Feedback view. To be more better check if

```
     <% TempData["Message"] != null { %>
     <%= TempData["Message"] %>;
     <%} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you try to access those as Model properties as follows:

```
<%= Model.ErrorMessage %>

<%= Model.SuccessMessage %>
```

Comment: Can you show me example how to add this exception to my model?

Answer (score 0):

use [TempData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary.aspx).

> You can use a TempDataDictionary object to pass data in the same way that you use a ViewDataDictionary object. However, the data in a TempDataDictionary object persists only from one request to the next, unless you mark one or more keys for retention by using the Keep method. If a key is marked for retention, the key is retained for the next request.
>
> A typical use for a TempDataDictionary object is to pass data from an action method when it redirects to another action method. For example, an action method might store information about an error in the controller's TempData property (which returns a TempDataDictionary object) before it calls the RedirectToAction method. The next action method can then handle the error and render a view that displays an error message.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Feedback(FeedbackForm Model)
{
    bool error = true;
    
    if(error){
        TempData["Message"] = "Error";
        TempData["Error"] = true;            
    }
    else{
        TempData["Message"] = "Success";
        TempData["Error"] = false;            
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Feedback", "Home");
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Feedback()
{
    string message = TempData["Message"].ToString();
    bool error = Convert.ToBoolean(TempData["Error"]);

    var model = new FeedbackModel{Message = message, Error = error};

    return View(model);
}
```